# Changing prototype of an object which was created with literal initialization

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to use ONLY [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) (not constructors). I have an object like this:

```
var o = {
  name : "Jack"
}
```

If I want to create another object which its prototype is `o` I use this syntax:

```
var u = Object.create( o );
console.log( u.name );//prints Jack
u.name = "Jill";
console.log( u.name );//prints Jill
```

Works fine! No problem. But now at runtime I want to change the prototype of `u` to something else. If `u` was created with a constructor like this:

```
function U () {}
U.prototype.name = "Jack";
var u = new U;
console.log( u.name );//prints Jack
```

OR

```
function U () {
  this.name = "Jack";
}
var u = new U;
console.log( u.name );//prints Jack
```

**But when using constructors, I can totally change the prototype**:

```
function U () {}
//totally changed the prototype object to another object
U.prototype = {
  dad : "Adam"
}
var u = new U;
console.log( u.dad );//prints Adam
```

Then whatever I added to the prototype of `U` would automatically be added to every object that is created after those changes. But how do I get the same effect with Object literals?

Please provide the simplest solution which has a clean and short syntax. I just wanna know if it's possible to do this manually. I don't want to use the non-standard [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) keyword either.

I've searched Stackoverflow and this is not really a duplicate of the following questions:

- [Adding Prototype to JavaScript Object Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592384/adding-prototype-to-object-literal)
- [Adding a prototype to an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452414/adding-a-prototype-to-an-object-literal)

Because I want to change the prototype after creation in a standard way (if possible). Something like `Object.setPrototype()` would be perfect, but that function doesn't exist! Is there any other way to simply set the prototype of an object that is created using object literal initialization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the current spec, you can't *change* an object's prototype once it's instantiated (as in, swap out one and swap in another). *(But see below, things may be changing.)* You can only *modify* the object's prototype. But that may be all you want, looking at your question.

To be clear about the distinction:

```
var p1 = {
    foo1: function() {
        console.log("foo1");
    }
};
var p2 = {
    foo2: function() {
        console.log("foo1");
    }
};

var o = Object.create(p1);
o.foo1(); // logs "foo1"
o.foo2(); // ReferenceError, there is no foo2
// You cannot now *change* o's prototype to p2.
// You can modify p1:
p1.bar1 = function() { console.log("bar1"); };
// ...and those modifications show up on any objects using p1
// as their prototype:
o.bar1(); // logs "bar1"
// ...but you can't swap p1 out entirely and replace it with p2.
```

Getting back to your question:

> If u was created with a constructor like this...Then whatever I added to the prototype of `U` would automatically be added to every object that is created after those changes. But how do I get the same effect with Object literals?

By modifying the object you passed into `Object.create` as the prototype, as above. Note how adding `bar1` to `p1` made it available on `o`, even though `o` was created before it was added. Just as with constructor functions, the prototype relationship endures, `o` doesn't get a snapshot of `p1` as of when it was created, it gets an enduring link to it.

---

ES.next is looking likely to have the "[set prototype operator](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproto_operator)" (`<|`), which will make it possible to do that. But there's no *standard* mechanism for it currently. Some engines implement a pseudo-property called `__proto__` which provides this functionality now, but it's not standardized.