# How to create a new object inherit an existing object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an animal object , and I want to create a dog object and it inherit from animal.

the following code is ok:

```
var animal = {
    name: "animal",
    voice: function () {
        return 'haha';
    }
};

if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
    Object.beget = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    }
}
var dog = Object.beget(animal);

dog.voice = function () {
    return 'wangwang';
};
document.writeln(dog.name);
document.writeln(dog.voice());
// animal 
// wangwang
```

but I want to implement the **Object.beget** function like this:

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
    Object.beget = function (o) {
        var F = {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return F;
    }
}
```

create an empty object,and change it`s prototype object to *animal object*, but it is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dog.voice is not a function
```

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong? thank you very much!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452414/adding-a-prototype-to-an-object-literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `Object.create`, which will create a new object whose prototype is the object passed as the first parameter:

```js
var animal = {
    name: "animal",
    voice: function () {
        return 'haha';
    }
};

if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
    Object.beget = (o) => Object.create(o);
}
var dog = Object.beget(animal);

dog.voice = function () {
    return 'wangwang';
};
document.writeln(dog.name);
document.writeln(dog.voice());
// animal 
// wangwang
```

Another option is to use `setPrototypeOf`, which will do what you were trying to do by assigning to `F`'s `prototype` property. But assigning to the `prototype` property is only meaningful for a *constructor function* (or `class`) - if you have an *object* (rather than a *constructor*) whose prototype you want to set, use `setPrototypeOf` instead. (assigning to the `__proto__` property can work too, but `setPrototypeOf` is better)

```js
var animal = {
    name: "animal",
    voice: function () {
        return 'haha';
    }
};

if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
    Object.beget = function (o) {
        var F = {};
        Object.setPrototypeOf(F, o);
        return F;
    }
}
var dog = Object.beget(animal);

dog.voice = function () {
    return 'wangwang';
};
document.writeln(dog.name);
document.writeln(dog.voice());
// animal 
// wangwang
```

But mutating the built-in objects like `Object` is very bad practice - consider another solution if at all possible.

Comment: While this is obviously preferable, can you explain why his version doesn't work?