# Why prototype consider in object but not in function instead

Tags: javascript, prototype

From this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), it made the appearance that `prototype` is a property of `Object`, however it seems more like `prototype` is a `property` of `function` instead?

Given the below code it's hitting `TypeReference`

```js
let Animal = {
  name: 'randomAnimal'
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
  console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
}
```

In order to make it work, instead of object, we change it to function instead as below

```js
function Animal (name) {
  this.name = name;  
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function () {
  console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
}
```

My question is more on try to understand the morale or reason behind why saying prototype is consider property of object, although one can argue that all functions are objects

Comment: `Object` is a function.

Comment: @melpomene: Stated clearly in the link I've shared. `All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object;` not functions I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype is an object property and functions *are* first class objects.

To make an object parameterizable during instantiation, we can create an object by means of a constructor function which is as you wrote:

```
function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name;  
}
Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " says hi!");
}
var lion = new Animal("lion");
lion.speak(); // "lion says hi!"
```

Here a name is given at the object construction.

But you can create objects also by using object initializers, like

```
let lion = { 
    name: "lion",
    speak: function() {
        console.log(this.name + " says hi!");
    }
}
lion.speak(); // "lion says hi!"
```

Naturally it is easier with a constructor, especially if you have several properties to initialize and/or several similar objects to construct.

Third way to create objects is to use Object.create(). It allows you to specify the prototype object on object creation, like:

```
var cat = Object.create(lion);
cat.name = "house cat";
cat.speak(); // "house cat says hi!"
console.log(lion.isPrototypeOf(cat)); // true
```

For info about objects in JavaScript, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Edit:
But by default all functions have a "prototype" member object as we don't know if the function is to be used as a constructor. Object literals or objects created with Object.create() won't have it.

```
console.log(cat.prototype); //undefined
```

As for adding prototype member object to an object literal, a stack overflow question: [Adding a prototype to an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452414/adding-a-prototype-to-an-object-literal?rq=1)