# Objects, prototypes and cosntructors in javaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

This is a kind of question very debated, but I think the reason is the lack of good documentation and good books on the subject.

When I study a language I do a lot of digging even if some of my tests are absurd, but I think the only way to understand things is doing all kinds of experiments.

I'm beginning with JavaScript and as much I code as more I'm confused.

Let's view the code (forget the no-senses by now and consider only the outputs):

```
function Vehicle()
{
    this.color = 'Blue'
}

var car = new Vehicle()

console.log('Vehicle.constructor: ', Vehicle.constructor)
console.log('car.constructor: ', car.constructor)

console.log('Vehicle.prototype: ', Vehicle.prototype)
console.log('car.prototype: ', car.prototype)

console.log('Vehicle.constructor.prototype: ', Vehicle.constructor.prototype)
console.log('car.constructor.prototype: ', car.constructor.prototype)

console.log('Vehicle.prototype.constructor: ', Vehicle.prototype.constructor)
console.log('car.prototype.constructor: ', car.prototype.constructor)



Output:

Vehicle.constructor: Function()
car.constructor: Vehicle()

Vehicle.prototype: Vehicle {}  // curly braces here
car.prototype: undefined

Vehicle.constructor.prototype: function()
car.constructor.prototype: Vehicle {}      // curly braces here

Vehicle.prototype.constructor: Vehicle()
TypeError: car.prototype is undefined
```

My conclusions:

Vehicle.prototype == car.constructor.prototype == Vehicle {}  // curly braces here 
Vehicle.prototype.constructor == car.constructor == Vehicle() // parenthesis here

Vehicle.constructor == Function() // uppercase 'F'
Vehicle.constructor.prototype ==  function() // lowercase 'f'

car.prototype == undefined  // undefined but not reported as error 
car.prototype.constructor   // Type error. Here 'car.prototype' is reported as an error

Now let's consider the similar code:

```
var car = {color: 'Blue'}

console.log('car.constructor: ', car.constructor)
console.log('car.prototype: ', car.prototype)
console.log('car.constructor.prototype: ', car.constructor.prototype)
console.log('car.prototype.constructor: ', car.prototype.constructor)


Output: 

car.constructor: Object()
car.prototype: undefined
car.constructor.prototype: Object {}  // curly braces here
TypeError: car.prototype is undefined
```

As we can see, here 'car.prototype' is **only** undefined, but 'car.prototype.constructor' is undefined and **also** 'TypeError'

The code above is tested in Firebug. I don't know this is Firebug's fault or JavaScript fault.

All of this puzzled me.

If this is OOP in JavaScript I think this is more ODP - Object (Dis)oriented Programming

**EDIT**

1) Why car.prototype is undefined when car.prototype.constructor is TypeError
2) Why both functions and objects have constructors and prototypes (see code above)?
3) What the meaning of this:

Vehicle.constructor.prototype: function()
Vehicle.prototype.constructor: Vehicle()
car.constructor.prototype: Vehicle {}

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. What exactly are you asking? We can answer questions like "what's the difference between a prototype and a constructor" or "why does x.y give undefined when x.y.z gives TypeError", but you're not asking anything specific. Seems to me like the best thing for you would be to find a good article on JavaScript's functions, prototypes and constructors and understand the relations between them. You can try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687093/Understanding-JavaScript-Object-Creation-Patterns), although there are countless others.

Comment: Basically I don't understand how prototypes and construtors differ and why can we have both associated with objects and functions, and also the meaning of object.prototype.constructor (or the inverse)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you declare an object using object literal notation

```
var newObject = {foo: 'bar'};
```

You are creating an object that inherits from `'Object()'` and has no prototype of it's own.

Notice when you call `'car.constructor'` it returns `'Object()'`. This is because that is the constructor JS uses in object literal notation.

When you call `'car.prototype'` it is undefined because object literals have no prototype of their own.

When you call `'car.constructor.prototype'` it returns an empty object since that is the essentially the value of `'Object()'`. It just creates objects.

in order for your objects to have their own prototypes you must establish a constructor and use

`'new myObject()'` to declare your objects.

I hope I've helped answer your question. Here are a few links that have more info:

[Adding Prototype to JavaScript Object Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592384/adding-prototype-to-object-literal)

http://doctrina.org/Javascript-Objects-Prototypes.html

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You should remember forever: Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object, as Function inherited from Object, any function is Object too. So, keeping in mind this sentence, look at this:

```
(function f(){}) instanceof Function;        // true
(function f(){}) instanceof Object;          // true, as Function is an instance of Object
({}) instanceof Object;                      // true
({}) instanceof Function;                    // false!

Function.prototype instanceof Object;        // true
Function instanceof Object;                  // true, as all objects in JS are inherited     from Object
Object instanceof Function;                  // true, as Object is a constructor function, therefor:
Function instanceof Function;                // true
Object instanceof Object;                    // true, but:
Date instanceof Date;                        // false

Function.prototype.constructor === Function; // true
Function.constructor === Function;           // true     

typeof Object === 'function';                // true, as Object is a constructor function
```

So, different braces indicate that prototype is always an object (curly braces), if it is defined, and constructor is always a function. That's all.