# accessing prototype of javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I can access the prototype object of a javascript function using the `.prototype` but when I cannot use `.prototype` on a javascript object literal.
 Please let me know why is this behavior inconsistent.

```
var add = function (a, b) {     return a + b; };
var s={name:'Pradeep'}
console.log('Function\'s prototype >> '+add.prototype)
console.log('Object\'s prototype >> '+ s.prototype)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/b5xhx80g/

Comment: `prototype` is a property of a `function` not of `obect`... Having said that..You may want to do like this.. `s.constructor.prototype`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592384/adding-prototype-to-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype property of a function is not the same thing as the function's prototype (inherited) methods.

`myFunction.prototype` is the object that will be used as the prototype of objects created using `myFunction` as a constructor (`new myFunction()`). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

What you're looking for is the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property, which accesses the inherited (prototype) methods of an object.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Using the __proto__ we can see the object's prototype.

Comment: The [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) uses `[[Prototype]]` to refer to the internal prototype property of objects that references the object's constructor's public *prototype*.