# Is there really no way to define a "component" without UI in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggeling already some days now. I'm searching for a way to define a React component without UI. My goal is to have several functions in one "component" (as I said without UI), which can be used by other components, but with all the benefits of `useState` etc.
I already, thought, there is a way, by defining components like this:

```
export const useExample = () => {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState('someValue');

    const getSomething = (parameter1, parameter2) => {
        return ...
    }

    return {
        getSomething
    };
}
```

I thought, I could import `useExample` in a component and then use the function `getSomething` like this:

```
import { useExample } from 'useExample.component.js';
//...

function SomeComponent(props) {
    //...
    useEffect(() => {
        const example = useExample.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
    },[]);
    //...
}
```

...but actually this seems not be working.

Then I get an error like this:

Uncaught TypeError:

> ...useExample.getSomething is not a function
> at eval...

All docs I find is telling me, that I need to return a JSX element. But I really cannot believe that in React there is no way to do this. Am I wrong?
I know, if I use plain JS, I'm able to do so, but I already tried this approach and there are many  other difficulties then with combining it with React components.
Did anyone have had a similar issue and found a solution to this?

Comment: useExample is a function, this function does not has a prototype like an object. I see that you tried to call like a object. Do you need a function or object? Because getSomething always work in useExample. It is not a prototype, it's a function in useExample. Change your mind.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592384/adding-prototype-to-javascript-object-literal you can check this approach.

Comment: Actually I need an object. As I wrote my first tries have been with standard classes of JS and creating instances of these classes. That worked fine until a certain step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to create is a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook), not a component.

You cannot call a hook in a `useEffect`, but since it returns an object containing the function, you can store this function in a variable and then call it in the `useEffect`.

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
    const { getSomething } = useExample();

    useEffect(() => {
        const example = getSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
    },[]);

    //...
}
```

Also be aware that if you call this function in the `useEffect`, you probably want to put it in the dependency array. And depending on the rest of your code, it also means you might need to wrap `getSomething` in a `useCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

Beside custom hooks, you can also use Render Props pattern. It goes like this:

```
export const Example = ({next}) => {
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState('someValue');

    const getSomething = (parameter1, parameter2) => {
        return ...
    }

    return next({
        getSomething
    });
}
```

And then, when you want to use that component, you use like this:

```
import { Example } from 'Example.component.js';
//...

function SomeComponent(props) {

    return <Example {...{
        next: (example) => {
            const something = example.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
            return <span>{something}</span>;
        },
    }}/>;

}
```

You can also use multiple non-UI components too: just stack them on top of each other to create a pyramid of doom like this:

```
import { Example } from 'Example.component.js';
//...

function SomeComponent(props) {

    return <Example1 {...{
        next: (example1) => {
            const something1 = example1.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
            return <Example2 {...{
                next: (example2) => {
                    const something2 = example2.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2);
                    return <span>{something1 + something2}</span>;
                },
            }}/>;
        },
    }}/>;

}
```

If you don't like the pyramid, you can use [my lib](https://github.com/callback-stack/cs-react) to flatten it down:

```
import { Example } from 'Example.component.js';
//...

function SomeComponent(props) {

    return cs(
        ["example1", ({}, next) => <Example1 {...{next}}/>],
        ["example2", ({}, next) => <Example2 {...{next}}/>],
        ({example1, example2}) => <span>{
            example1.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2) + 
            example2.getSomething(parameter1, parameter2) 
        }</span>,
    );
}
```

Comment: This goes against React's principles and in my honest opinion it just makes code harder to read

Comment: @zoran404 which React principle are you refering to?

Comment: You made a lib that has the same functionality as the official api. It doesn't even make the code shorter. Aside from that you should avoid render props in general. And in practice you will never see nested render props like in your example. If you want to ask for additional explanation you can ask me on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2100372/zoran404

Comment: @zoran404 So by "against React's principles", you mean React has a principle of "should avoid render props in general"? Or are there any other principle that I missed in your explanation? I can't use stackoverflow's chat, please email me (quanla2003@gmail.com) your contact. Thanks